# How to edit a Display Template directly with Visual Studio

Tags: 2013, display-template

I'm working on a Display Template for the standard search Refinement web part.

The problem is that every time that I need to change it (with Visual Studio 2013) I have to pass from a manual delete and upload new html file (under Master pages>display templates>filters) that is implementing the display template.

Is it possible to change pre-processed/published .js somewhere directly on sharepoint server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the MasterPage Gallery to a network drive, then just edit the html file in Visual Studio.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2616712

Comment: Thanks Omar good idea. Now I have permission problems with "Open with Explorer" button :-/